# Spring app error: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error when I am trying to incorporate a Bean and Autowired for a custom logger for my spring project. Any help would be appreciated.

CustomLogger.java:

```
@Component
public class CustomLogger {
    public CustomLogger(String env) {}
}
// ... public void methods here
```

LoggerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggerConfig {
    @Value("${my-env}")
    String env;

    @Bean
    public CustomLogger myLogger {
        return new CustomLogger(env);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired private CustomLogger myLogger; // Trying to inject object created in LoggerConfig class
// GET mappings
}
```

Error:
`Unsatisified dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Stirng' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: you could have directly injected the constructor argument using @Value. Is there any particular reason why you are creating the Component using @Bean? Spring will take care of creating the CustomLogger bean and you can autowire it anywhere you like.

Comment: @HossainCyrus CustomLogger will turned be a library that will be used by a couple of projects. So, I am not injecting into that class since I will be importing it into different projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the `CustomLogger` component.  By annotating this class as `@Component`, Spring is trying to create the bean but doesn't have a value it can inject in the constructor.  Since it appears that you have this value defined as a property, modify your `CustomLogger` component to look like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomLogger {
  @Value("${my-env}")
  private String env;

  public CustomLogger() {}
}
```

Or, since you're also constructing this bean in a configuration class, just drop `@Component` from `CustomLogger`

Comment: Thank you so much. As you suggested, removing the @Component fixed the issue. I did not inject directly into CustomLogger as I'll eventually convert it into a library.